# vue-styleguidist does not serve because: Attempted import error: 'h' is not exported from 'vue' (imported as 'Vue')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, react-styleguidist, vue-styleguidist

I'm trying to run `vue-styleguidist server` but I'm getting this error:

```
Attempted import error: 'h' is not exported from 'vue' (imported as 'Vue').
 @ ./node_modules/vue-styleguidist/lib/client/rsg-components/Preview/PreviewAsync.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/rsg-components/Playground/Playground.js
 @ ./node_modules/vue-styleguidist/lib/client/rsg-components/PlaygroundAsync/PlaygroundAsync.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/rsg-components/Playground/index.js
```

When I try `vue-styleguidist build` command the related file to docs is generated but is not completed and shows just props of component not methods.

I'm using `Vue` version: 2.0,
`webpack` version:  4.44.1, and
`styleguidist` version: 4.44.17

Answer (score 0):

Try to update `react` and `react-dom` to version 17 (add to perrDependencies if missing)

Comment: I use VueJS v2 and every time install all dependencies